# How to log in user automatically after registration?

Tags: php, authentication, session, registration

I am having trouble writing code how to log in user automatically after registration. I am using epoch and when user passes payment it redirects him to site but he is not logged in. I already did redirection with window.location = 'www.site.com/members/?username={$member.username}'; and it redirects me to that page with correct username in URL but the user is not logged in. I just need help on how to write logic that logs in user. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

header.php (Here is user redirected after successful registration and here I need to write login logic. Currently I am just being redirected to login page. In elseif it would go that logic.)

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])) {
    header("Location: www.site.com/tour/login.php");
} elseif(isset($_GET["username"])) {
    login_function();
}

?>
```

custom_functions.php (Here is my login function that logs in user on site)

```
function login_function() {

    session_start();
    require 'connection.php';

    $_SESSION["username_error"] = $username_error;
    $_SESSION["password_error"] = $password_error;

    $v_username = $_POST['username'];
    $v_password = $_POST['password'];

    $username = validation($v_username);
    $password = validation($v_password);

    $remember = isset($_POST['remember']);

    if(empty($username))
    {
        $_SESSION["username_error"] = "<p>Please enter your username!</p>";
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
    }

    if(empty($password))
    {
        $_SESSION["password_error"] = "<p>Please enter your password!</p>";
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
    }

    if($username && $password) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM member_auth WHERE username = :username";

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);

        $stmt->execute();

        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $cryptpass = $user['cryptpass'];

        if($user === false){
            $_SESSION["username_error"] = "<p>User doesn't exist</p>";
            header("Location: login.php");
            exit();
        }   elseif($user) {
            $newpass = crypt($password, $cryptpass);
                if($cryptpass == $newpass) {
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    if($remember == "on") {
                        setcookie("remember", $username, time()+3600);
                    }
                    header('Location: login_success.php');
                    exit();
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["password_error"] = "<p>Password is not correct!</p>"; 
                    header("Location: login.php"); 
                    exit();
                }
            } 
    }
}
```

login.php

```
<?php 

session_start(); 

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/login_assets/css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/login_assets/css/media.css">
<script src="/login_assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/login_assets/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->

</head>

<div id="login_body">
<header class="clear hBlack">
    <div class="jLogo"><a href="/"><img src="/login_assets/images/logo.png" alt=""></a></div>
</header>
<div class="logArea clear">
    <form action="custom_functions.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div class="logbox">
    <div class="box clear">
        <h2>Members Area</h2>
        <div class="logTypes">
        <input type="text" name="username" class="logtextbox" placeholder="Username or email">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['username_error'])){ echo $_SESSION["username_error"]; unset($_SESSION["username_error"]); }  ?></span>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="logtextbox" placeholder="Password"><br>
        <span class="text-danger"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['password_error'])){ echo $_SESSION["password_error"]; unset($_SESSION["password_error"]); }  ?></span>
        <!-- <input type="text" name="captcha" class="logtextbox" placeholder="Enter the code shown below"><br>
        <img style="margin: 0 auto;" src="captcha.php">
        <span class="text-danger"></span> -->
        <div style="text-align: center">Remember my login: <input name="remember" type="checkbox"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="logBtn" name="submit">
    </div>
    </form>
    <div class="logtext1">

    </div>
    <div class="logtext2">

    </div>
</div>
</div>
<footer class="clear">

</footer>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide your registration and login form details. So that we can provide solution.

Comment: @BalaChandar I added login form, but registration is done through epoch

Answer (score 0):

Your registration logic looks fine for me. Your header checks whether the user has logged in before, which is stored in the session variable.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])) {
    header("Location: www.site.com/tour/login.php");
} elseif(isset($_GET["username"])) {
    login_function();
}
```

I don't understand why you call login_function again. If the Session Variable "loggedIn" is true, the user has been logged in already. Why do you want to call login function again. If you need to fetch data for that user, you need to store the user id in a session variable and use that to make the request.

Comment: Well currenty with that code I am being redirected to login form page (this header("Location: www.site.com/tour/login.php");) , which means that user is not logged in and I want him to be after registration

Comment: @Marko I understand. If he is not logged in, he will be redirected to login.php. But after login you want to go back to the exact same page? Or what's the issue?

Comment: User can log in successfully from login form that is not the problem. I just want after registration is done successfully (from epoch) that that user that registered automatically be logged in on to site

Comment: @Marko Okay I get it, so after registration you want it to be logged in automatically. Not sure, if that approach is a good way, normally you will be redirect to login and login again. But if you want to do it you just wanna set the session variables after registration in the php.

Comment: Epoch registration is from other domain. So I passed that username of registered user in URL in order to be able to fetch it and now based on that I want to get the login done. Can you help?

Comment: @Marko Okay I finally understood. You might wanna send your Username and password (which can be insecure) via POST to your own domain. Then you can run the login process as you have these variables.

Comment: Yeah I already have username. When I register I passed username in url on my own domain www.site.com/members/?username=myusername . Based on that I need to login user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202398/discussion-between-davidev-and-marko).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login automatically after you login register and login process should be like this,

1. when user registration done, set the `$_SESSION["loggedin"]`.
2. the login page should check if `$_SESSION["loggedin"]` was setted, if setted head to login success page.

---

You can also head to login success page when registration done, without bypass the login page.